# Can't see stories on android emulator for react-native storybook

Tags: android, react-native, storybook

I'm building a mobile app with `React Native` and `Storybook`. But somehow, I can't see my component lists in the android emulator but can see my actual app screen.

### ScreenShot

This is the screenshot of my android emulator and this is my actual app.

[image: Android Emulator]

### Versions and configurations

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "sushi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007 -h 192.168.1.2",
    "prestorybook": "rnstl",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.23",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is `storbook/index.js`

```
// if you use expo remove this line
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from "react-native";

import {
  getStorybookUI,
  configure,
  addDecorator,
} from "@storybook/react-native";
import { withKnobs } from "@storybook/addon-knobs";

import "./rn-addons";

// enables knobs for all stories
addDecorator(withKnobs);

// import stories
configure(() => {
  require("./stories/index");
}, module);

// Refer to https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/tree/master/app/react-native#getstorybookui-options
// To find allowed options for getStorybookUI
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
  // host: Platform.OS === "android" ? "10.0.2.2" : "0.0.0.0",
  host: Platform.OS === "android" ? "192.168.1.2" : "0.0.0.0",
  asyncStorage: require("@react-native-async-storage/async-storage").default,
});

// If you are using React Native vanilla and after installation you don't see your app name here, write it manually.
// If you use Expo you should remove this line.
AppRegistry.registerComponent("%APP_NAME%", () => StorybookUIRoot);

export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

### How do I start storybook

- Run `adb reverse tcp:7007 tcp:7007` (This is only once)
- Start android emulator
- Run `yarn storybook`
- Run `yarn android`

### Error log

No error log on metro server and the terminal that storybook running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the storybook in your ./App.js:

`import StorybookUIRoot from './storybook';`

Now add the component to return in the App function:

`return <StorybookUIRoot />`